# What is the format of the timestamp fields in a SonarQube database

Tags: sql, timestamp, sonarqube

What is the format of the timestamp fields in a SonarQube database (Windows machine).

Here's a few fields from the table "issues" that seem to have timestamps:
- created_at
- updated_at
- issue_creation_date

Here's some sample values:

- 1479328731000
- 1500653407000
- 1529361516289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is those are timestamps in miliseconds.

More importantly, it looks like you're trying to access the SonarQube database directly. If you're trying to do scripting calls, SonarQube supports an API for command-line calls that is quite thorough. Information on this can be found here:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API

Comment: You are correct that I'm trying to automate calls to our SonarQube results. It looks like this requires "curl". I've never used this but will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like timestamp in miliseconds:

- 1479328731000 = 16 November 2016 20:38:51 GMT
- 1500653407000 = 21 July 2017 16:10:07 GMT
- 1529361516289 = 18 June 2018 22:38:36.289 GMT